# How to write the data in file just like excel format (table format) in C?

Tags: c

In cJSON, we can store the data in key-value format. Because of that it is easy to fetch the value using key.

```
{
 "age":35
}
```

I want the store the data to file in table format in C language.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| name1 | 22 |
| name2 | 23 |
| name2 | 33, 22, 34 |

Also, how should I fetch the value based on the name. flow is like i will get the some name name2 then first I will search that in Column A if it present than ok else any error. If its present fetch the value of the name.

I search on google but did not any solution. Also, I not getting any idea from where to start.

Right now,I m storing this using cJSON, but its takes lots of memory.

Sorry for the bad explanation.

Comment: You probably want to write your data in CSV. If you don't have to handle quotes, you can do it by hands, it will be easy. Otherwise you'd rather use a library.

Comment: "Excel format" can refer to a lot of formats read or written by different versions of Excel.

Answer (score 1):

As @mmeisson suggested, using the CSV format would be easiest and only require a small amount of C language code to implement. Imagine a text file that contains the following:

```yaml
name1, 22
name2, 23
```

This can be easily produced by using printf() calls:

```c
for (int i = 0; i < col_a_count; i++)
{
    printf("%s, %d \n", col_a_name[i], col_b_value[i]);
}
```

To read the data back (I assume this is necessary at some point) then you can read each line from the text file and do a string split function with the "," delimiter.

The problem however is how to deal with the multiple values for any given name. For example, your second example for "name2" contains three entries as "33, 22, 34". So if you chose "," as your delimiter character, then the data gets messed up. To solve this problem you could choose a unique delimiter for the COLUMN data, and another unique delimiter for the COLUMN B list. For example:

```c
for (int i = 0; i < col_a_count; i++)
{
    printf("%s; ", col_a_name[i]);
    for (int ii = 0; ii < col_b_count; ii++)
    {
        printf("%d", col_b_value[ii]);
        // If more B COL data then add secondary delimiter
        if (ii < (col_b_count - 1)) printf(", ");
    }
}
```

Now the text file that is output should look like this:

```yaml
name1; 22
name2; 23
name2; 33, 22, 34
```

And as you read in the data later, you want to split each line first with the ";" delimiter, then with the "," delimiter for each of the second parts.